# React Native Expo Request failed with status code 404

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am trying to do a request to my server in a react native expo app on an ios device.

My server is on heroku and is with HTTPS.

here is the request code

```
axios.post(`${SERVER_URL}/users`, {
      data: {
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber.value,
        countryCode: '374',
        firstName: firstName.value,
        lastName: lastName.value
      }
    })
    .catch(err => console.error('sign up err', err))
    .then(res => {
      console.log('res', res.data)
    })
  }
```

And here is what error is displayed

`sign up err Error: Request failed with status code 404`

I also tried using `fetch` but get same 404 error.

And this is what I get on my phone

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message it seems like your URL is not well formed. You have an extra slash (`/`).

```
_response: {
  status: 404,
  message: "Not found"
},
_url: "https://join1.herokuapp.com//users"
```

If `SERVER_URL` variable has a slash at the end of it, delete that slash or delete the one before the user.

**Sample**

```
axios.post(`${SERVER_URL}users`, { /* some config */ })
```